# Timestamps for the last three business days

Tags: php, timestamp

I have been trying to find a way to reliably get the timestamps for the last three business days, regardless of the input date and am having difficulty. I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

This is what I tried:

```
    $date = date() - 60*60*24*3; 
    $timestamps = array();
    for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++){
       $timestamps[] = strtotime($date  . ' ' . $i . ' weekdays');
    }
```

I am looking for something as follows:

```
Input: lastThreeBusinessDays(date()); //Friday August 1 2014
Output (Array with timestamps for the following dates): 
Thursday July 31 2014, Wednesday July 30 2014, Tuesday July 29 2014 

Input: lastThreeBusinessDays(date()); //Saturday August 2 2014
Output (Array with timestamps for the following dates): 
Friday August 1, Thursday July 31 2014, Wednesday July 30 2014

Input: lastThreeBusinessDays(date()); //Sunday August 3 2014
Output (Array with timestamps for the following dates):
Friday August 1, Thursday July 31 2014, Wednesday July 30 2014
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the date passed is in a form of Y-M-D or similar, the only solution I can think of right now is to convert the date input from numeric to text using something like

    $newdate = strtotime($date);
    $day date('D', $mydate);

and then use switch to output the correct dates. For example, if $newdate == 'Saturday' then output Friday.. etc

I know this is not a complete solution, but it may actually spark something up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp has seconds granularity, so getting the timestamp of a day is quite ambiguous. The following code (assuming **business days** means every day but saturday and sunday) does what requested:

```
$timestamp = time();

$timestamps = array();
for ($n = 0; $n < 3; ++$n) {
    // The following cycle skips saturdays and sundays
    do {
        $timestamp -= 60*60*24;
    } while (date('N', $timestamp) > 5);
    $timestamps[] = $timestamp;
}
```